# XCode Cannot Find AppKit

Tags: xcode, ipad, kobold2d

I'm learning iPad development and I'm refactoring my project to use Kobold2d. It's been going well, but I'm stuck with trying to initialize a CCLabelTTF with the labelWithString:dimensions:hAlignment:vAlignment:fontName:fontSize: initializer, bit the issue is that for hAlignment and vAlignment, the expected values (CCTextAlignment and CCVerticalTextAlignment) have been depreciated. I read that the values to use are NSTextAlignment, which are found in the AppKit framework.

Here's where things get tricky; XCode seems to refuse to acknowledge the existence of the AppKit framework. When I go to the "target->Summary->Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and try to add a framework, the AppKit doesn't show as an option. Still, I'm able to find it and add it by searching in System/Library/Frameworks and adding it from there. Yet even with it added, XCode will still not allow me to do "#import ". It's even more odd, since the cocos2d classes which use AppKit have no issues whatsoever with importing it.

I'm at a complete loss as to why my project seems to refuse to allow me to use the AppKit framework; is there some sort of Framework search path inclusion that must be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AppKit is an OS X framework. You can't use it in an iOS app. Import UIKit instead, which is the iOS version of AppKit. It defines NSTextAlignment too.

Comment: Why does Cocos2d get to use it then? Also, what should I use for the hAlignment and vAlignment values? Or should I abandon CCLabelTTFs altogether and use a different CCLabel?

Comment: Cocos2D is both for OS X and iOS. The iOS part probably uses UIKit, the OS X part uses AppKit. I don't know how CCLabelTTF works, sorry.

Comment: I think the best solution is going to be to do the initializer without the alignments and to readjust the position. Thanks for clearing up the framework confusion.